# Wordpress post tags are not working

Tags: wordpress, tags

I ma fetching post and tags manually and forming tags url properly but still tags link not working. On click In Browser inspect network tab sending ajax request to admin-ajax.php automatically.

```
if (is_array(get_the_tags($post->ID)) || is_object(get_the_tags($post->ID))) :
   foreach(get_the_tags($post->ID) as $tag)
    {
      echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '" title="'.$tag->name.'" class="'.$tag->slug.'">' . $tag->name . '</a></li> ';
     }
endif;
```

Links to verify; http://139.162.60.231/fow/

Html Formed :

```
<a href="http://139.162.60.231/fow/tag/startup/" title="Startup" class="startup">Startup</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();

if (is_array(get_the_tags($post_id)) || is_object(get_the_tags($post_id))) :
   foreach(get_the_tags($post_id) as $tag)
    {
      echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link($tag->term_id) . '" title="'.$tag->name.'" class="'.$tag->slug.'">' . $tag->name . '</a></li> ';
     }
endif;
```

Comment: Both looks same apart storing post id on separate variable

Comment: post values static set and check

Comment: post values static set and check   ex:  $post_id=118

Comment: Display link . Didn't get please explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162798/discussion-between-tarang-koradiya-and-krishnaisdinesh).